# Changing / Removing Video Sound android

Tags: android, video, media-player

**is there any way to change the video sound ? Like removing the one that the video has and putting some music on the background ?**

What i'm doing is that, i want to record a video and play some music on the background and then save the video with this music as its sound.

Like in the Harlem Shake apps . . .

**If it is possible, can you tell me how it can be done ?**

Thanks in Advance.